# Как сделать реферальную ссылку Aiogram

Tags: python, telegram-bot, aiogram

```
@dp.message_handler(content_types=['text'])
async def get_message(message):
    if message.text == "Получить ссылку":
        await bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 
                               text=f"*Ваша ссылка:*", 
                               reply_markup=keyboard.dryg, 
                               parse_mode='Markdown')
```

Что нужно добавить к этому коду, чтобы ввести реферальную систему, выглядеть должно так.
Человек вводит команду `/ref` снизу всплывает клавиатура `получить ссылку`(скрин ниже), далее что добавить: ссылку бот ему выдает он ее копирует отправляет другу, друг по ней переходит, бот сразу же отправителю ссылки пишет "ваша скидка 1%"
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

У aiogram есть такая штука как deeplink. Вот как ее юзать.

```py
from aiogram.utils.deep_linking import get_start_link, decode_payload
from aiogram import types

# хендлер для создания ссылок
@dp.message_handler(commands=["ref"])
async def get_ref(message: types.Message):
  link = await get_start_link(str(message.from_user.username), encode=True)
  # result: 'https://t.me/MyBot?start='
  ## после знака = будет закодированный никнейм юзера, который создал реф ссылку, вместо него можно вставить и его id 
  await message.answer(f"Ваша реф. ссылка {link}")



# хендлер для расшифровки ссылки
@dp.message_handler(commands=["start"])
async def handler(message: types.Message):
    args = message.get_args()
    reference = decode_payload(args)
    await message.answer(f"Ваш реферал {reference}") #здесь в  reference должен быть юзернейм, того кто создал ссылку
```

Возможно где-то накосячил но вроде правильно. Вот еще ссылка на [документацию](https://docs.aiogram.dev/en/latest/utils/deep_linking.html?highlight=deep).

Comment: Лучший фидбэк на этом сайте, спасибо вам, зацени функционла бота @Avitolog1bot:)

Answer (score 1):

Хочу немного поправить автора предыдущего поста: в конце нужно писать не "Ваш реферал", а "Ваш реферер", т.к. если пользователь перешел по реф. ссылке, то он сам является рефералом, а юзер, по чьей ссылке он перешел - реферер

Comment: В опубликованном сообщении не содержится решения вопроса. Когда ваша [репутация](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) достигнет необходимого уровня, вы сможете [оставлять комментарии к любому сообщению](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); на данный момент, пожалуйста, [внесите улучшающую правку в ваше сообщение, чтобы оно отвечало на вопрос без дополнительных уточнений от автора](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). — [из очереди проверок](/review/late-answers/857630)

Answer (score 0):

В новой версии Aiogram немного, но коварно изменили имена полей из предыдущего решения.
Я нашел метод:

```
async def create_start_link(bot: Bot,
                            payload: str,
                            encode: bool = False)
```

Вот так это работает:

```
from aiogram.utils.deep_linking import create_start_link, decode_payload

@router.message(Command('ref'))
async def mt_referal_menu (message: Message, state: FSMContext, bot: Bot):
    link = await create_start_link(bot,str(message.from_user.id), encode=True)
```

Принять данные из реферальной ссылки получилось вот так:

```
@router.message(Command('start'))
async def process_start_command(message: Message,state: FSMContext,bot: Bot,command: Command = None):
  if command:
    args = command.args
    reference = decode_payload(args)
```