# Можно ли как-то регистрировать пользователей по рефферальным ссылкам в ТГ (группа или бот)?

Tags: python, telegram

Есть ТГ бот. Есть также сопуствующая ТГ группа.

Нужно сделать рефферальную программу для этого бота средствами ТГ - либо через бота, либо через группу. Используя рефферальную ссыку или код, то есть, как оно обычно и делается.

Но, есть пожелание: **чтобы пользователям не приходилось рефферальный код как-то копировать, вставлять, что-то с ним делать....** Хотелось бы, чтобы пользователи как-то регистрировались через реф. код, как это делают на обычных сайтах - по простой ссылке. Чтобы,  перешёл и - "вас пригласил Иван Петров. Вы регистрируетесь под ним как рефферал.. Нажмите кнопку ОК."

Можно ли это как-то сделать в ТГ?

---

**обнов #1**

Сейчас вопрос стоит в том, как прочитать этот рефферальный код, когда новый пользователь первый раз переходит по ссылке **в ТГ-бота**

```
t.me/fdsafdsafdsfd_bot?aff_code=1234
```

Как прочитать этот `1234` **в боте**?

Бот потом отправит эту инфру на сторонний сайт, где она сохранится в БД.

Comment: Я без БД не вижу решения.

Comment: С БД. Но, БД на стороннем сайте

Comment: Ну значит к нему придётся делать запрос, в бэке нужно будет реализовать подачу данных по запросу. При регистрации пользователя нужно добавлять его в БД и соответственно имя того кто отправил реф. ссылку, тут ТГ не обойдёшься...

Comment: @ΝNL993 Да. Сейчас вопрос стоит в том, как прочитать этот рефферальный код, когда новый пользователь первый раз переходит по ссылке **в ТГ-бота**

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Как сделать реферальную ссылку Aiogram](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1374650/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d1%81%d0%b4%d0%b5%d0%bb%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-%d1%80%d0%b5%d1%84%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%bb%d1%8c%d0%bd%d1%83%d1%8e-%d1%81%d1%81%d1%8b%d0%bb%d0%ba%d1%83-aiogram)

Comment: @oleksandrigo нет тут дупликата - я не использую тут `aiogram`

Comment: Так а вы вообще не написали что вы используете

Comment: @oleksandrigo ничего не использую

Answer (score 0, accepted):

t.me/fdsafdsafdsfd_bot?start=1234
Пользователь перейдет в бота по ссылке и нажмет кнопку /start
Далее в функции старт, прочитайте сообщение которое пользователь отправил, отделите сплитом '/start' и у вас будет '1234'

Пример:

```
def START(update, context):
   ref = update.message.text.split()[1]
```

Comment: В `/start` будет сообщение `/start`. Нет? Иначе как тогда прочитать  `1234`?

Comment: `Пользователь перейдет в бота по ссылке и нажмет кнопку /start`. А как я его **заставлю** нажать кнопку start? Тем более, откуда там вообще созьмётся **кнопка** start?

Comment: Вообщем, опиши лучше подробнее, с примером

Comment: в сообщение /start может лежать все что угодно(конечно есть ограничения).

Comment: Ну, если он хочет пользоваться ботов, то ему придется нажать на старт

Comment: Как прочитать параметры, которые были переданы в `/start`?

Comment: Добавил в ответ

Comment: Чтобы давать ссылку на бота с аффилиатным кодом, мне нужно будет **обязательно** давать эту её с коммандой `/start`? ---> `t.me/fdsafdsafdsfd_bot?start=1234`? То есть, вот так - нельзя будет --> `t.me/fdsafdsafdsfd_bot?aff=1234` ?

Comment: Да, можно и так

Comment: Что значит "можно и так"? А как ещё можно?

Comment: Можно любое слово вставить после вопросительного и так же любое после равно, но там есть ограничения, которые я не помню, лучше всего документацию почитать или поэкспериментировать

Comment: Я просто обязательное наличие `start?` ДО, а не про то, что можно вставить  ПОСЛЕ

Comment: "Можно любое слово вставить после вопросительного и так же любое после равно"
я уже ответил

Comment: Ах ты неслух такой! Ну бабка тебе сейчас даст!