Реферальная система aiogram
Как проверять является ли ссылка реферальной и как из неё достать ID того кто пригласил? Aiogram 3

Используйте deep-linking

https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1374650/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D1%81%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D1%80%D0%B5%D1%84%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D1%83%D1%8E-%D1%81%D1%81%D1%8B%D0%BB%D0%BA%D1%83-aiogram

В aiogram есть Command и CommandStart фильтры, куда можно указать "магию" для проверки аргументов команды (см. раздел Magic filters).
Пример:
from aiogram.filters import CommandStart, CommandObject

@router.message(CommandStart(magic=F.args.cast(int)))
async def referral_start(message: Message, command: CommandObject) -> Any:
    referral_id: int = int(command.args)
    return message.answer("Referral ID is: {id}".format(id=referral_id))
    

Очень рекомендую дополнительно ознакомиться с разделом документации Deep Linking.
